# What tool do you use to Analyze Qualtrics CSV data

Tags: descriptive-statistics, factor-analysis, survey, computational-statistics

I’ve conducted a survey and have the csv export file as the results.

What tool do you recommend to analyze the relationships between different factors?

I think I can manually do ETL and put the data into DB and analyze, but I’m thinking if there is any easier to just load the file and do some statistics analysis.

Comment: R and Python. Both are have large number of tutorials to do data analysis programmatically and compatibility with large number of file types. You can pick any of them based on your previous experience.